# How to fix crash when call env->SetStaticIntField(cls, jfid, 0) method

Tags: android-ndk

I called `env->SetStaticIntField(cls, jfid, 0);`  app crashed .

addr2line tool  found this:
`/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r19/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/cxa_demangle.cpp:2125`

My application is using `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)`   and  `cppFlags "-std=c++14"`

c++ method  like this :

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_zhumu_xiaot_com_ndkdemo_MainActivity_operateStaticInt(JNIEnv *env, 
jobject instance) {
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(instance);
    jfieldID jfid = env->GetStaticFieldID(cls, "staticint", "I");
    jint jsataticint = env->GetStaticIntField(cls, jfid);

    env->SetStaticIntField(cls, jfid, 80);
}
```

Comment: Is that your entire stacktrace? If so, how do you know that it's the `SetStaticIntField` that causes the crash? Also, where is your error checking?

Comment: If you use proguard make sure you've added the field to the proguard rules

Comment: Thank you ！The reason is that the method did not write the return value. It was called incorrectly. I call java: String s = ""+operateStaticInt (); because there is no return value